# Set an image as background for TableView with Storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, background, storyboard

Storyboard is causing to me a lot of problems! :(

Now I'm trying to put an image as a background of a tableview in iOS.
I've done a png image with transparency in photoshop and I've imported it into my project.

** The first question is: is it possible to set the image background in storyboard?
I thought that a good idea was to create and image view and put it on my table view... but storyboard doesn't allow my to do this.

** I've also tried to add the background image via code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_background.png"]];

...
}
```

I obtained an horrible result with a black background instead of white, even if the png is transparent!

Moreover I've read that to optimize performances, it should be better to avoid transparent background for cells.

**So, what it the best way to set an image as a background for a table view with storyboard?**

Thank you in advance,
yassa

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a method to set a background view for a tableView

```
[ tableView setBackgroundView:<#(UIView *)#> ];
```

And then add an UIImageView (but only for 3.2+)

Avoid using backgroundColor for this kind of things ^^

Using only story board I don't know :-] but with this method it should work.

Btw check that your tableView & cell have a clear backgroundColor, may be the problem too.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you fro your help, but maybe I didn't get the point.
I know that with Interface Builder, I can add a transparent image view over (or below) the table view.
With storyboard instead, I cannot put anything over the table view!

So, I've added a new view controller in my storyboard (not linked with any other view) and I've put on it an image view.
How can I reference this UIView in my code, in order to user the setBackgroundView method?